# how to do a select on characters separated by pipe character

Tags: formula

the following is a sample of data in a field:-

|10|
|1|
|9|1|
|10|1|

I need to be able to say, include data where there is a |1| in the field.  I have tried the following without luck.  Any suggestions appreciated:-
1. SUBSTRING(JobSites,2,CHARINDEX('|',JobSites)) - 
2. where JobSites = '%|1|%'
I cant use 1 as the character lengths are not consistant.

Comment: What platform would you like to use? What coding languages do you know?

Comment: I'm using SQL 2008 R2

Answer (score 1):

Pipes are perfect for using a delimiter.  I would take the below steps to accomplish this.  To Tara's point, you can accomplish the parsing with your technology of choice (excel, python, SQL, etc).

```
1) Parse each number into a different column
2) Set the value in each column = 0 if != 1
3) Filter using a having statement  where the sum of each column is >= 1.
```

In short, what you're trying to do with your where clause is not going to be accurate.

Comment: Let me know if you need guidance on any of the above steps. I'd be glad to assist further or point you in the right direction.

Comment: thanks Susan.  the issue I'm having with step 2) is that the character length is not stagnant.  I.e.  a field can have "|10|1|" or |9|,  so I cant state ...take the first three characters   (as 10 is two but a 9 is one.  How do I get around this pl?

Comment: A dynamic width shouldn't be an issue.  For simplicity, use the import/export tools to download your data to a flat file, and delimit by pipe.  You'll have an uneven number of columns as a result, but when you upload it back into SQL, you can convert the NULLs to Zeros. Those zeros shouldn't pose an issue for your later steps.  If you havent used the SQL wizard before, i've included a link to get you up to speed on it.  But you should choose 'SQL Server NAtive Client 11.0' as your data source, and flat file (specify csv in the file type) as your destination.

Comment: http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/feature/The-SQL-Server-Import-and-Export-Wizard-how-to-guide

Comment: I am unable to export and reimport unfortunately as the SQL runs in a application called QlikView so I need a formula to put each character into a separate field

Comment: Im not familiar with QlickView, but I am familiar with Tableau. I know in tableau you cannot do procedural SQL. For example, create temp tables, declare variables, etc.  You can only do simple selects to join the tables. Is this also the case with Qlickview?

Answer (score 0):

this ended up being sufficient..JobSites = '%|1|%'